How to create the down part of a table?

So I need help with making the down part of a table.

Can be more specific please? Like, way way way more specific? What is "the down part" of a table? Also, asking other people to do your work for you is not what this site is for as stated in the help center

If you are asking about how to model the table legs and supports, that's just basic modelling and is not something we can help you with here. Suggest you watch a few of the Blender modelling tutorials such as these ones found with a simple Google search: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=how+to+model+a+table+in+blender.

Idk how to make the support tho

And the tutorials on how to make a table don't have a support part

Have you tried a Boolean operation or the Boolean modifier? Place the center wooden slat in the center of the legs, then duplicate it, make it a bit shorter in Edit mode (scale) and rotate it by 45 degrees around the Z-axis. Then add a Boolean modifier.

I dont know what a boolean modifier is but I will look into it

Try a Boolean modifier. The only challenge is to place the wooden slats properly. This can be done with the 3D Cursor.
Step 1 - create the table legs and the center slat:

create an Empty object at the world origin (0,0,0) for the Mirror modifier, and create a floor plane
create a table leg and the center slat. Put them on the floor and move them to the new Bool collection (M). You need it later.
add a Mirror modifer to mirror the leg and create 4 of them.


Step 2 - prepare the diagonal slats:

duplicate the center slat and move it a bit to the side.
move it out of the Bool collection (M)
in Edit mode, set select the upper face, and move the 3D Cursor to it (Ctrl+S,2 > Cursor to Selected)
note/copy the Z value. It's the height for the slats.
switch to Object mode, keep the diagonal slat selected and set its origin to the 3D Cursor via menu Object > Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor. This will move the little orange dot to the 3D Cursor


Step 3 - put everything together

Select diagonal slat first, then the table leg and move the slat the to the leg (Ctrl+S, 9 Selection to Active). Alternatively, you can move and use 3D Cursor.
Select the slate, and paste/enter the height that you have copied/noted in step 2 for the Z value of the tranformation to move it down. Then rotate it by 45° around the Z-axis so it's now diagonal.
scale it along the local X-axis to make it shorter -or- just adjust the values in the side panel.
also, scale it a tiny bit along the Z-axis so the Boolean modifier works properly.
add a Mirror modifier and use the Empty for the center
for the final cut, add the Boolean modifier and use the Bool collection


If you're happy with the result, you can apply the modifier and join everything (Ctrl+J). Now you can add a Bevel modifier (the Bevel modifier doesn't work very well with the Boolean modifier if it's not applied).
Don't forget to apply the Scale, Rotation and Location (Ctrl+A).
